# Angular 9 Chart.js line chart with multiple line by date based

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

This question already asked but not solve my problem.

I implemented `Chart.js` in my `Angular 9` application. There expect chart values are not coming.

I have an API response in that I want to make `lineChartLabels` as below mentioned way [stackblitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-woy6tt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

This is my API response:

```
let data = [
    {operatorName: 'OSEN+', date: '05-04-2023', totalCount: 1},
    {operatorName: 'OSN+', date: '12-04-2023', totalCount: 7},
    {operatorName: 'MBC', date: '01-06-2023', totalCount: 1},
    {operatorName: 'OSEN+', date: '02-06-2023', totalCount: 1},
    {operatorName: 'MBC', date: '09-06-2023', totalCount: 1},
    {operatorName: 'MBC', date: '16-06-2023', totalCount: 1},
    {operatorName: 'MBC', date: '23-06-2023', totalCount: 15}
];
```

I want to set `lineChartLabels` with the API response.

Expected Data set:

```
this.lineChartData = [
      { data: [1, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], label: 'OSEN+' },
      { data: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 15], label: 'MBC' },
    ];
    
this.lineChartLabels = ['05-04-2023', '12-04-2023', '01-06-2023', '02-06-2023', '09-06-2023','16-06-2023', '23-06-2023' ];
```

Here if `operatorName` not present in `lineChartLabels` set as value `0`.

Code:

```
let operators = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.operatorName))];
      
      let subLabelDatasets = operators.map((x) => {
        let datasets = [];
      
        for (let operator of operators) {
          datasets.push(
            data.find((y) => y.operatorName == operator && y.date == x)?.totalCount || 0
          );
        }
      
        return {
          label: x,
          data: datasets,
        };
      });
console.log(data)
      console.log(subLabelDatasets)
```

Expected result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Notes

(1) To make my answer more didactic, I changed the name of this variables:

- `operators` to `uniqueOperators`
- `x` to `uniqueOperator`

(2) I changed some `let` to `const`, as it never reassigned

(3) **Updates**

- handle multiple operators on same date
- added complete code

#### Code

You need to updated your logic to something like that:

```
const uniqueOperators = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.operatorName))];
const uniqueDates = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.date))];

const subLabelDatasets = uniqueOperators.map((uniqueOperator) => {
  // find by operatorName and date in `data`
  // if not found, fill with `0`
  let datasets = uniqueDates.map((uniqueDate) =>
    data.find(
      (item) =>
        item.operatorName === uniqueOperator && item.date === uniqueDate
    )?.totalCount ?? 0
  );

  return {
    label: uniqueOperator,
    data: datasets,
  };
});
```

this will output an array like you expect:

```
[
    {label: 'OSEN+', data: [1, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}
    {label: 'MBC', data: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 15]}
]
```

This code will work even if the API outputed data contains multiple operators on same date like that:

```
const data = [
  { operatorName: 'OSEN+', date: '01-06-2023', totalCount: 1 },
  { operatorName: 'MBC', date: '01-06-2023', totalCount: 2 },
];
```

will ouput:

```
[
    {label: 'OSEN+', data: [1]}
    {label: 'MBC', data: [2]}
]
```

and you can use `uniqueDates` to replace the hard coded `lineChartLabels` this way

```
this.lineChartLabels = [...uniqueDates];
```

### Complete code

(tested on your stackblitz demo)

```
export class AppComponent {
  /**Line chart */
  public lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';
  public lineChartData: any = [];
  public lineChartLabels: any = [];
  public lineChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  /**Line chart */

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let data = [
      { operatorName: 'OSEN+', date: '05-04-2023', totalCount: 1 },
      { operatorName: 'OSEN+', date: '12-04-2023', totalCount: 7 },
      { operatorName: 'MBC', date: '01-06-2023', totalCount: 1 },
      { operatorName: 'OSEN+', date: '02-06-2023', totalCount: 1 },
      { operatorName: 'MBC', date: '09-06-2023', totalCount: 1 },
      { operatorName: 'MBC', date: '16-06-2023', totalCount: 1 },
      { operatorName: 'MBC', date: '23-06-2023', totalCount: 15 },
    ];

    const uniqueOperators = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.operatorName))];
    const uniqueDates = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.date))];

    this.lineChartData = uniqueOperators.map((uniqueOperator) => {
      // find by operatorName and date in `data`
      // if not found, fill with `0`
      let datasets = uniqueDates.map((uniqueDate) =>
        data.find(
          (item) =>
            item.operatorName === uniqueOperator && item.date === uniqueDate
        )?.totalCount ?? 0
      );
    
      return {
        label: uniqueOperator,
        data: datasets,
      };
    });

    this.lineChartLabels = [...uniqueDates];
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!